# Headphones only play sound for a short time

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth, headphones

When I first turn on my computer, my headphones connect just fine and it'll stay connected. If my computer has been on for a while (not sure how long), it won't play sound (but still connect). All I hear are popping noises. If it helps, I'm using Windows 10 with Uproar Wireless Bluetooth headphones.

Answer (score 0):

All right, I don't know what happened but this doesn't happen anymore.
They work perfectly fine now. I don't know if it was the stick or what, but it works now.